# set zoom in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating project using javascript. In my project I have integrated google map.The google map works successfully. My problem is when I set zoom level below 2 then it gives me error.I want to set zoom level below 2. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDsPOaE1uhGq8hXk9MoX3sAzDeDj5lSLps&libraries=geometry,drawing"></script>
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 1.5,
            minZoom: 1.5,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            },
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Zoom needs to be an integer value.

It doesn't specifically state that anywhere in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels) I can find, but only integer values work.

- related enhancement request in the issue tracker: [Issue 9948: Fractional zoom level(fine zoom)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9948)
- related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 694: Bug: Some browsers do not correctly report the cursor position when at fractional zoom levels (i.e. that is a non whole number zoom such as 8.9) via the "Mouse Move" event.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=694)
- related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 695: Bug: Map.getLatLngBounds does not return the correct lat/long bounds for a Map object at fractional zoom levels](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=695)

Created an issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 10090: Bug: document requirement that zoom be an integer value](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10090)